# save/load object with large numpy matrices

Tags: python, numpy, dataset, mmap

I have a dataset class where some of the members are matrices that can get very large; sometimes too large to keep in RAM. Therefore, I allocate these matrices as numpy.memmaps.

I would like to save this object to a single file on disk.

Since I've already allocated the matrix on disk as a separate memmap file, the object currently gets saved as two files: the .pkl that stores the object without the matrix, and a separate memmap file for the matrix. I've overloaded `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` to save the path to the memmap in the .pkl file. This is pretty hacky.

Are there any ways to save the pickled object and its giant matrix member into a single file?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience using `memmaps`.  So, though I have good success using [PyTables](http://www.pytables.org/moin/PyTables), I can't really compare the two.  With `PyTables` you get in- and out-ofcore allocation, flexible data compression, and a standard file format that is much better suited to storing large numerical data sets than `pickle`.

`PyTables` creates structured HDF5 files.  You therefore get the benefit of portability to other analysis systems, including `Matlab` and a wide selection of file viewers and data inspection tools designed for HDF5.

This doesn't answer your original question about pickling objects, but given the flexibility you pick up by switching to `PyTables` it may be worth it for you to change disk data formats.

If you really need to stick with `Pickle`, you could break your huge array up by creating and saving views into it, then saving the smaller views with `shelve`.